# A basic question on first order linear PDEs

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I can not figure out how we obtained the  ratio:

[image]

ِA follow up question:

Where do we use the assumption that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I have edited the question. It should be clear and simple now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will clarify your doubts.

(I just skipping the previous part)

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~dx ~+~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~dy ~+~\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~dz ~=~0 \tag1$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}~dx ~+~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}~dy ~+~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}~dz ~=~0 \tag2$$
By cross-multiplication, 
$$\frac{dx}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}=\frac{dy}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}}=\frac{dz}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\tag3$$
which can be written in the following ratio form,$$dx:dy:dz=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right):\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right):\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)\tag4$$
Again $$\frac{dx}{P}=\frac{dy}{Q}=\frac{dz}{R}\tag5$$can also written in the following ration form $$dx:dy:dz=p:Q:R\tag6$$
Combining  $(4)$ and $(6)$, we have 
$$dx:dy:dz=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right):\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right):\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}~-~\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)=P:Q:R$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I still do not understand how we can obtain (3). When you say "cross multiplication" what do mean ? Is it the cross multiplication of two vectors ? So we have two zero vectors (the vectors in (1) and (2)) whose cross multiplication must vanish, so each component of the cross product is zero?

Comment: For cross-multiplication, see the link https://www.math-only-math.com/cross-multiplication-method.html

Comment: I see. It is just solving for $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ after all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome @Medo

Comment: Where do we use the assumption that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent ? I am guessing it implies that the denominator of $dz$ does not vanish..but how?

Comment: If $~u~$ and $~v~$ are linearly independent, then you can write the general solution of $~Pp+Qq=R~$ can be written in the form  $~\phi(u,v)=0~$. For more details you have to read your book (from where you got the problem) and also `chapter 28` .

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but here, it says "Since $u$ and $v$ are independent functions, we may solve for the ratios...". So assuming $u$ and $v$ is independent justifies the next step which is solving for the ratios.